# SQL Case with calculation on 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, alteryx

I have a value table and I need to write a case statement that touches 2 columns: Below is the example

```
Type    State   Min Max Value 
   A    TX       2  15  100
   A    TX      16  30  200
   A    TX      31+     500
```

Let say I have another table that has the following

```
Type State Weight Value 
 A   TX    14      ?
```

So when I join the table , I need a case statement that looks at weight from table 2 , type and state - compare it to the table 1 , know that the weight falls between 2 and 15 from row 1 and update Value in table 2 with 100

Is this doable ?

Thanks

Comment: CASE WHEN t2.Weight BETWEEN t1.Min AND t1.Max THEN t1.Value ELSE Whatever END

Comment: Considering not having `31+` and instead using an enormous number for the `Max` value. This will make it easier to always do numeric comparisons; most solutions suggested appear to have made this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `Min` and `Max` columns in first table are of `Integer` type

You need to use `INNER JOIN` on ranges

```
SELECT *
FROM   another_table a
       JOIN first_table b
         ON a.type = b.type 
         AND a.State = b.State
         AND a.Weight BETWEEN b.min AND b.max
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns 0 if there aren't rows in this range of values.

```
select Type, State, Weight,
       (select coalesce(Value, 0)
        from table_b
        where table_b.Type = table_a.Type
              and table_b.State = table_a.State
              and table_a.Value between table_b.Min and table_b.Max) as Value
from table_a
```

Answer (score 0):

For an Alteryx solution: (1) run both tables into a Join tool, joining on Type and State; (2) Send the output to a Filter tool where you force Weight to be between Min and Max; (3) Send that output to a Select tool, where you grab only the specific columns you want; (since the Join will give you all columns from all tables). Done.

Caveats: the data running from Join to Filter could be large, since you are joining every Type/State combination in the Lookup table to the other table. Depending on the size of your datasets, that might be cumbersome. Alteryx is very fast though, and at least we're limiting on State and Type, so if your datasets aren't too large, this simple solution will work fine.

With larger data, try to do it as part of your original select, utilizing one of the other solutions given here for your SQL query.